# ARCGIS iOS - map layers memory issue

Tags: ios, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, arcgis

In my application I used arcgis sdk. I have 3 different map so I used 3 tiled map service layers. And also I have a graphic layer to show symbol for selected specific region on the map. My app; first connects the services with credential and then adds the layers to the map view. So far there is no problem. After loading all of layers, I started to use AGSQueryTask and AGSIdentify task for some query operations. Here the problem starts. The debugger gives me  "Received memory warning. Level=1". I continue to do zoom/pan, and extra query operations. After a while, my app crashes giving no error. I reviewed my code, googled about my problem, looked around in arcgis forums however I didn't find a solution and good explanation. I tried my app with 1 map not 3 but the warning and crashing didn't disappear. I also deal with hidden property of layer view again there is no improvement.

After all, is there anyone who knows a solution or an explanation or an assumption to my memory problem?

P.S. I also debugged my code with nszombienabled and guard malloc thanks to stackoverflow:) In  this process I came across ": CGBitmapContextInfoCreate: unable to allocate .. bytes for bitmap data". Is my memory problem related to this error?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds really like some memory leaks or not releasing memory which is not used anymore by your app.

There is no general solution to be given, because the cause of those problems could be anywhere and be anything.

What you could do is:

1. ensure that you have defined `didReceiveMemoryWarning` methods in your classes and that you try to free not used memory there;
2. running your app under the Leaks and Memory Allocation profiling tools and see what you can to about what they report to you;
3. if you do not have memory leaks, try and use [snapshot analysis](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2011/03/08/using-heapshots-to-find-abandoned-memory.html) to find abandoned memory.

> In this process I came across ": CGBitmapContextInfoCreate: unable to allocate .. bytes for bitmap data". Is my memory problem related to this error?

If you fill up the memory, the allocation call can fail... this is rather an effect, more than a cause.

Comment: Even though I know these, I'll revise my code again. Thanks for answer anyway.